# I have an error eloquent query unexpected: !=

Tags: eloquent

My query is the following:

```
 $users = User::where("admin", <>, '1')->where('id', <>, $my_id)->get();


The error is the following:

Sintax error

unexpected: !=
after ','
expected: exit, integer, double, identificer, STRING, VARNAME, variable, String, String, clone, function, isset, empty, list, array, _CLASS, _METHOD, _FUNCTION, _NAMESPACE, _DIR_, ª, define, include, include_once, eval, require, require_once

POSSIBLE Syntax Error (check preceding valid syntax error)
unexpected: !=
POSSIBLE Syntax Error (check preceding valid syntax error)
unexpected: )
Introduce Variable 
-----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

I unknowed the error. Someone could help me. thank you!
expect exit, integer, double, identifier, STRING_VARNAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't just pass `<>` or `!=` it has to be a **string**!

```
$users = User::where("admin", "<>", '1')->where('id', "<>", $my_id)->get();
```